# How to count posts in tags within time limit

Tags: posts, tags, count

When we list tags we can get the count and even sort by count like this:

```
$tags = get_tags([
    'orderby' => 'count',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
    'include' => $term_ids,
]);
```

**But how can we get the count of posts for the last week for example?**

I would like to get the `"trending tags"` last week, but can not find any nice way to get this done in WordPress without making my own SQL query. Is that the way to go or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

WP Core doesn't have a way to pull tags by how many posts were published associated to a tag in a given time period. You'll need to roll your own solution. Use `$wpdb->prepare` as a best practice; the [Codex article on the wpdb class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) should give you the info you need to run the query in a WP way.